# Objects In Viewport Not Rendering Properly

Tags: 3d-view

The objects are fine shape-wise, but when It's being rendered in the viewport, It has random triangles cut out, there are no modifiers applied, and I'm using blender 3.0.0, and I'm rendering the viewport with EEVEE.

This was rendered in the viewport with EEVEE[image: This was rendered in the viewport with EEVEE]

This was rendered with cycles.(colors are random and for testing, that's not the issue.)
[image]

Comment: please try to change clip start from those 0.000003 to something like 0.001